# Use UDP port for GDB connection in Eclipse

Tags: linux, eclipse, udp, kgdb

I'm using KGDBoE to for debugging Linux kernel.
KGDBoE start a server at a certain udp port, I can easily connect to the server running on the embedded target using gdb via command line.

Now I want to use Eclipse IDE to make gdb debugging more interactive.
Problem is that I can't find option to use UDP port for gdb connection in Eclipse Attach Application Debug launch.

Anyone has idea how to accomplish that.

Making things simpler, I want to use UDP connection rather than TCP to connect to the GDBserver running on my embedded board. Its's very straightforward using GDB CLI but I want to use Eclipse for that.

Thanks